# MySQL results different 5.6 to 5.7 (AWS RDS)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, django-orm

In the process of upgrading from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7 on RDS I'm finding differences in results returned for a number of queries.

For instance (table names obfuscated):

```
SELECT `model_s`.`id`,`model_s`.`pr`,`model_s`.`o_id`,`model_s`.`uploadee`
    ,`model_s`.`created_at`,`model_s`.`updated_at`,`model_s`.`o_ref`,`model_s`.`i_ref`
    ,`model_s`.`stss`,`model_s`.`u_fol`,`model_s`.`sdd`,`model_s`.`an_t_id`,`model_s`.`rean`
    ,`model_s`.`dpp`,`model_s`.`bg_t_cr`
FROM `model_s` 
INNER JOIN `o_o` ON (`model_s`.`o_id` = `o_o`.`id`)
WHERE (
    `model_s`.`pr` IN
    (
        SELECT u0.`id` AS col1
        FROM `pr_pr` u0
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `pr_stfr_pr_p` u1 ON (u0.`id` = u1.`pr`)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `acc_strf` u2 ON (u1.`stfr_id` = u2.`id`)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `acc_us_strf_as` u3 ON (u2.`id` = u3.`stfr_id`)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `pr_us_pr_p` u5 ON (u0.`id` = u5.`pr`)
        WHERE (u3.`usr` = 7 OR u5.`usr` = 7)
    )
    AND NOT (`model_s`.`stss` = d)
    AND `o_o`.`name` LIKE %my text%
)
ORDER BY `model_s`.`created_at` DESC
```

In this case, 5.6 returns 1 result and 5.7 returns 2 results (the latter being the expected behaviour).

Options for the DB are merely the default RDS 5.6 and 5.7 options (none changed at all).

Any idea why with default options we see such a difference between 5.6 and 5.7? (Please, no comments on complexity/readability/optimization of the query - its generated by the Django ORM and is a question for the future...)

Comment: Are the database *contents* exactly the same?

Comment: Yes - this is from a reproducible set of automated tests. Also done a double check by dumping contents from 5.6 and importing to 5.7.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in 5.6 that was fixed in 5.7.

Comment: `LIKE %my text%` is missing quotes around `%my text%`

Comment: *In the process of upgrading...* and *the latter being the expected behavior*. What's the problem? It's good if an update fixed the issue unintentionally.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem? They haven't updated to 5.7 yet.

Comment: The query doesn't really look that complex (no correlated subqueries, session variables, or even incomplete groupings). I'd double check the database contents again. Instead of dumping from one into the other (which could change the contents), dump both and compare.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr - magically upgrading a version to fix an issue and not understanding why it fixed it.... sounds like a bad idea. The behavioural change could quite easily break something else.

Comment: @Uueerdo - Already compared the contents of the DBs (at least via Django dumpdata) and they are the same (except obvious datetime fields etc.)

Comment: Any type conversions going on in the fields your conditions use? Differences in table/field collation?